# Play framework: passing parameter to custom tag

Tags: java, tags, playframework

I want to pass the name of a field as a parameter to a [custom Play! framework tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/templates#tags):

```
  #{ifError ${_field}}
    <ul class="err">
    #{errors ${_field}}
      <li>${error}</li>
    #{/errors}
    </ul>
  #{/ifError}
```

But all I get is the exception:

```
Template execution error (In /app/views/tags/errorList.html around line 1)
Execution error occured in template /app/views/tags/errorList.html. Exception raised was MissingMethodException : No signature of method: Template_1008.$() is applicable for argument types: (Template_1008$_run_closure1_closure2) values: [Template_1008$_run_closure1_closure2@2da75e1b] Possible solutions: _(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), get(java.lang.String).

play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException: No signature of method: Template_1008.$() is applicable for argument types: (Template_1008$_run_closure1_closure2) values: [Template_1008$_run_closure1_closure2@2da75e1b]
```

How can I pass the parameter to my tag?

**Solution**

I have slightly modified the solution of "Codemwnci" and ended up with the following template code:

```
#{ifError _arg}
  <ul class="err">
  #{errors _arg}
    <li>${error}</li>
  #{/errors}
  </ul>
#{/ifError}
```

This template is called like this `#{errorList 'document.title' /}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are already inside a piece of Groovy code by using the tag syntax `#{..}`, you do not need to use the Expression syntax (i.e. you don't need to use the `${..}` syntax).

Also, the `errors` tag does not take any input, you instead need to pass the field name into the error tag. You can check [this documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/tags#iferror) for details of the `error` tag.

The following should work for you

```
#{ifError _field}
  <ul class="err">
    <li>#{error _field /}</li>
  </ul>
#{/ifError}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! It is important to pass a named parameter to the tag as long as the default name for a single parameter `arg` is not  used. Btw [errors has an optional parameter](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#errors).

Comment: so it does. that is useful to know!